# How to get notifications when a donation is made to my non-profit on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-notifications

A donation was made to a non-Profit via a Facebook page I manage and we didn't know about it until over a month later when Facebook sent a "Payments Remittance" email. We would like to be notified the instant a donation is made to us, but it doesn't appear there is a way to do so. In page settings you can download transaction reports but obviously that isn't convenient.

Answer (score 0):

I asked Facebook Support and they replied with the information below. If anyone in the future finds out they have enabled these types of notifications, please post a new answer and I'll mark it as the solution.

> The functionality you’re requesting is currently unavailable. Please note that I have forwarded your feedback to the appropriate team. We appreciate your patience and understanding as we work to enhance our product.
>
> However, if you'd like to check to see how much has been donated to date, you have access to two types of reports in the Publishing Tools section of your Page Admin view. Donation reports are updated at the end of each day.
>
> Daily Transaction Report - This report includes detailed information on each donation made to your organization, whether through the Donate button or through a fundraiser. This report includes fields like First Name, Last Name, Amount Donated and Email Address (if the donor decides to share it). These are updated daily, but won't show up on your report for 48 hours. For example, a donation made on January 1, 2019 will appear in a report available for download after January 3, 2019.
>
> Payout Report - This report shows the funds that will be transferred into your account and are available at the end of every bi-weekly period. The resulting payout occurs about two weeks after the end of the donation period (if your organization has accrued at least $100 in donations). If you haven't accrued $100 in donations in a given period, the amount you've raised will roll over into the next two-week period, until you have accrued $100 in donations.
>
> To access these reports:
>
> 1. Go to Publishing Tools on the top of the page.
> 2. Select Donation Settings on the left side of the page.
> 3. Click Download Donation Reports.
> 4. Note: These reports are downloaded as a .cvs file.
>
> Thanks,
>
> [redacted name]
>   Facebook Payments Specialist